# Cross Validation sklearn - How the splits are performed?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm currently dealing with a classification problem and have a question about the cross validation functionality of the `sklearn` / `scikit-learn` Python module. Consider the following call:

`cv_scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(rfc, X, y, cv=self.cv_folds, n_jobs = 1)`

Where `self.cv_folds` is a number, e.g. 5. The function actually returns an array with the scores of each fold of the cross validation. But now I need to know *how* the function performed the splits. That means, which records have been assigned to test and train set each iteration. To make it more clear, let's consider a small example data set:

```
(1)  0 1:9151.57142857 2:158.0 3:0.0136674259681 4:5.0 5:438.0 6:6.0  7:9.25388888889
(2)  1 1:3884.8 2:20338.0 3:0.0280373831776 4:194.0 5:320.0 6:9.0 7:42.8808333333
(3)  0 1:5219.5 2:241.0 3:0.00171821305842 4:55.0 5:1745.0 6:3.0 7:42.8808333333
(4)  0 1:1386.0 2:2125.0 3:0.0161290322581 4:315.0 5:309.0 6:5.0 7:14.8722222222
(5)  1 1:5508.375 2:27.0 3:0.00302245250432 4:1231.0 5:2315.0 6:7.0 7:591.213611111
(6)  1 1:12488.0 2:404.0 3:0.020942408377 4:31.0 5:190.0 6:4.0 7:9.25388888889
(7)  1 1:1748.4 2:0.0 3:0.00293685756241 4:376.0 5:1361.0 6:4.0 7:96.5372222222
(8)  1 1:3401.25 2:476.0 3:0.0714285714286 4:16.0 5:41.0 6:3.0 7:3.19722222222
(9)  1 1:2748.4 2:614.0 3:0.25 4:3.0 5:15.0 6:4.0 7:3.19722222222    
(10) 1 1:1386.0 2:2125.0 3:0.0161290322581 4:47.0 5:309.0 6:5.0 7:14.8722222222
```

(X) Indicates the line number, the first value the class label and the values from 1-7 are features indices, each followed by its value. Now I want to know the exact split strategy of the function. To make it more clear the following examples show two different ways of how the data can be split into test and train set each iteration:

**Example 1:**

Iteration 1: (1) - (2) to test

Iteration 2: (3) - (4) to test

Iteration 3: (5) - (6) to test

...

**Example 2**

Iteration 1: (1) and (3) to test

Iteration 2: (2) and (4) to test

Iteration 3: (5) and (7) to test

...

Does anyone know the exact split strategy the function is using? Or can anyone state a function to take a look into these splits and not only into the results?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `cv_folds` is a cv-object, then take a look at `list(self.cv_folds)`, and you will find a list of tuples `[(train1, test1), (train2, test2), ...]`.

If `self.cv_folds` is only a number, then consider being explicit about setting a cross-validation iterator e.g. as follows:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold, StratifiedKFold
## Choose one of the two next lines
cv = KFold(self.cv_folds)   # for regression
cv = StratifiedKFold(y, self.cv_folds)   # for classification

cv_scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(rfc, X, y, cv=cv)
```

Now, with `list(cv)` you can recover all indices of the train/test splits.

Note that the default cross-validation iterators depend on the nature of your estimator (classifier or regressor), so it is always better to be explicit about it if you need this level of detail.

Comment: First `cv_folds` is a number, I added this information to my post. And thank you very much, this looks exactly like the solution I'm looking for. I'll try this and may add another comment if I still should have any question. Thank you.